# Are currently sold versions of "Mein Kampf" censored?

Tags: hitler, literature

[*Mein Kampf*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mein_Kampf) was illegal in a lot of countries for a very long time. 
Yet, while browsing [GoodReads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/54270.Mein_Kampf) I realised reading it might be very interesting to get some insight in how the horrors of WW2 came to be.

I noticed the year of publishing on said list was 1973. With A. Hitler’s demise being in 1945 that seemed rather difficult to believe, so I am assuming the book has been modified/edited. There were quite a few earlier translations so I am positive it is not simply the year the **translated** version was released.

So how likely is it that the book has been censored? If a government decides to illegalize it, publishing it with changed contents does not sound very far-fetched.

Comment: Are you talking about the German edition? IIRC, the state of Bavaria has or had the copyright and decided against publishing it as a critical/study edition a few years back.

Comment: Dutch, in this case.

Comment: Okay, I can't comment on the situation in the NL. FWIW, the bavarian ministry of finance had the copyright of the German edition until it expired in dec. 2015. 2016, the Munich based IfZ (Institut für Zeitgeschichte, institute for contemporary history) published a heavily annotated edition (to volumes, 6kg, 3500 footnotes, 5 years of work by many historians, 60€). Selling copies of Mein Kampf was never illegal in Germany AFAICT but reprints were forbidden via the copyright.

Comment: The Mein Kampf was not strictly illegalized; as the state of Bavaria held its copyright it simply denied permission to anyone to reprint it, so any modern copies would have been illegal everywhere due to copyright laws, regardless of specific censoring laws. IIRC the copyright was set to expire soon (or maybe it already has) and there were talks of providing an "official" version with appropiated critical comments to prevent the spread or uncommented and/or modified versions. Any 1973 reprint would have been done by a shoddy organization and should not be trusted to be the original text.

Comment: ... and the english copyright was sold in the 30ties and are or were held by random house (who donated the earnings from the book). I doubt that Mein Kampf is actually illegal in the NL (but I could be wrong!) and suggest hitting your local library?

Comment: @mart Looked into the situation here for a bit; While it isn't strictly illegal, the government holds the rights to it (Up until last year, actually) and chose _not to publish it_.

Comment: If you are reading Mein Kampf in English, then I highly recommend [the Ford translation](https://www.amazon.com/Mein-Kampf-New-Ford-Translation/dp/0984158421). It is one of the most interesting and insightful books that I've ever read, especially the first three chapters. I'm Jewish, and found surprisingly little antisemetism in the book. The books helps one understand not only Hitler, but also to understand the Jews' place in early 20th century Europe.

Comment: @mart I've never understood why Bavaria would do something like that; it seems like the best possible way to make people curious.  What part of "those who do not learn from history are doomed to repeat it" do they not understand?

Comment: @dotancohen I have an "unexpurgated" English edition published in 1939. Tucked inside is a cutting of a review from the Daily Telegraph (London) of 23 March 1939. The review describes it as an "unabridged English version". The translator was a James Murphy of Abbots Langley. I have never really got beyond the first sentence which contains the word "destiny" (*schicksal* in German). It refers to the fact that he was born at Braunau am Inn on the border of Germany and Austria. Anyone who begins their biographical notes with *destiny* surely has to be a narcissus of some order.

Comment: @WS2: Your concern is actually addressed in the foreword to the Ford translation. The first few chapters are autobiographical, Ford pretty much states that only a fool would write his autobiography in a style which does not make him the hero of the story.

Comment: @dotancohen Did you mean "only a fool...in a style which DOES make him the hero of the story"?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Mein Kampf was illegal in a lot of countries for a very long time.

As already noted in a comment, it was never illegal in Germany. You could sell and buy any existing copies. Reprinting it was not allowed by the copyright holder (the German federal state of Bavaria inherited it from Hitler after his death).

The copyright expired 70 years after Hitler's death and so reprinting it is allowed again. Germany decided that instead of leaving the reprinting business to a lot of private right wing organizations, the "Münchner Institut für Zeitgeschichte" (Munich Institute of History) published a version that contained the original print accompanied by a comment: "Hitler, Mein Kampf: Eine kritische Edition"

Except for illegal reprints, anything printed between 1945 and 2015 are probably books that feature excerpts, comments and texts by other authors. But again, the book itself was never "illegal". Existing copies could always be sold, bought and read freely.

Comment: While this provides some interesting context it does not directly answer the question of whether currently circulating copies are in any way censored.

Comment: What does "Hitler, Mein Kampf: Eine kritische Edition" translate to in English?

Comment: @KodosJohnson: "eine kritische edition" means "a critical edition". In other words, an addition that takes into consideration variations in previously published (and unpublished) editions. Depending on how scientific it is, it may feature an apparatus that records differences in different manuscripts, or differences in texts that claim to cite it. Since it was not published for the first time that long ago, I don't know how critical this critical edition really is. I haven't seen it, but I suspect they're just calling it a "critical edition".

Comment: @ShimonbM - as I understand from a radio interview, the "critical edition" means that it has been heavily annotated throughout (putting in context and pointing out outright falsehoods) and (as far as I could tell from the interview) without changes to the original text.

Comment: I would translate "eine kritische Edition" to "annotated version".

Comment: @BZN_DBer I cannot possibly know every existing book. The one's sold in German between 1945+ and 2015 are not *censored*, but they are not complete either, as they contain only excerpts because quoting from the book was allowed for other books, but reprinting was not.

Answer (score 7):

There's some indication that the English version circulated in the late 1930's deliberately omitted or reduced Hitler's anti-semitism and aspirations on Europe.

US Senator **Alan Cranston** had read the German version, and found an English translation in Macy's Bookstore in New York in 1939.  On browsing he noted it was too short and too light, and had significant differences.  So he and a friend worked to publish an "anti-Nazi" version of the book in English.

> “I wrote this, dictated it [from Hitler’s German text] in about eight days, to a battery of secretaries in a loft in Manhattan,” Cranston told the Los Angeles Times in 1988. They produced a tabloid edition of 32 pages, reducing Hitler’s 270,000 words to 70,000 to yield a “Reader’s Digest-like version [showing] the worst of Hitler.”

[Further info](http://articles.latimes.com/1988-02-14/news/mn-42699_1_mein-kampf) from Los Angeles Times archive, dated 1998-02-14

So depending on the source, you might indeed be reading a deliberately-altered version, beyond the changes that plain translation would produce.

Comment: I'm not sure of the level of quoting expected in this SE.   Should it be mostly left in the link, or should more of the information be brought through to this post?     A holus-bolus quote of the LA Times story would be too much I think.

Comment: My personal view is that quotes should contain just enough to support the case that's being made (in context) without needing to view the source document - this quote seems fine.

Comment: Hm. So he thought the previous edition was too short, so he decided to make an.. even shorter?

Comment: @pipe - Perhaps it was a 'two can play at THAT game' thing? The edition he found was making Hitler not look so bad by carefully choosing it's contents, while his edition showed the worst of Hitler by doing the same thing.